# Make ListView item click to create new Intent with the JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-intent

I want to create a new intent for each of the item in my ListView. But first I am trying to see if the data holder.title can be read through log. It cannot. I tried to use Toast, but I also receive error on makeText().

What is wrong with my codes? I am not a java programmer, forgive me if this is a simple problem.

This codes is based on the solution from [How to parse Sub JSONArray and display image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701747/how-to-parse-sub-jsonarray-and-display-image)

I have modify some of the codes but I am confident enough that it should not affect this part of the code.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Data item = mObjects.get(position);
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());



        item.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

//Intent to be here. Now I am testing to see if data can be passed but it can't
                Log.e("log_tag","This is being clicked");
            }
        });

        holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);
        if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
            holder.mTask.execute();
        }


        return rowView;
    }
```

EDITED! I tried for hours for the codes above but it looks hopeless. So I look into the MainActivity class. And at least something came out. When i click the list item, "This is being clicked" is being showed. But i am still not able to show any of the JSON data upon clicking. And I am wondering how do i do intent from here.

Edited Again.

I change some code after seeing more codes online. And still stuck.

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
mAdapter = new Adapter(this, mSource);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    //private Object title;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);  
        //Selected item
        //String product = ((TextView) View).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),o.get("title"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
```

Comment: How do you set onItemClickListener for the type of Data...?

Comment: Hmm i am not sure.. but i have updated my post cos i see something that is closer to what i want

Comment: what u want ? i think get data of selected row ?

Comment: yup that's right. Get data of selected row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this Steps:

**1**. Create bean class of the getters and setters methods.

**2**. Create a ArrayList.

**3**. Store the values into bean class.

**4**. Add the bean class object into arraylist.

**5**. Now, On the click of the listview item, pass the bean class object using `putExtra`.

Go this way.

**EDIT:**

Bean Class:

```
 public class ActivitiesBean implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String title;
public String image;
........ 

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

..............


}
```

Java class:

```
 ActivitiesBean bean;
ArrayList<Object> listActivities = new ArrayList<Object>();

............................



 public class FetchActivitesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int i =0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
         pgb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         ............

                    Here your JSON code

            for (i = 0; i < jsonnodes.length(); i++) 
            {


                JSONObject jsonnode = jsonnodes.getJSONObject(i); 

                JSONObject jsonnodevalue = jsonnode.getJSONObject(node);

                bean = new ActivitiesBean();

                bean.title = jsonnodevalue.getString(title);
                bean.image = jsonnodevalue.getString(image_fid);

                                    .....................  


                listActivities.add(bean);


            }               
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
      }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pgb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        displayAdapter();
    }
}

public void displayAdapter()
{
    adapter = new ActivityAdapter(this, listActivities);
    contests_listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    contests_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

            bean = (ActivitiesBean) adapter.getItem(position);

            Intent in1 = new Intent(Activites_Activity.this, Activity_display.class);
            in1.putExtra("ActivityObject", bean);
            startActivity(in1);
        }

    });

}
```