# android json picture parsing

Tags: android, json, image

hello ı am trying to learn json parsing and ı solve some thing but ı have problems ı can take informations in my listview but ı cant take picture image it my log says

my code is in here ı change url and some strings [How to parse Sub JSONArray and display image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701747/how-to-parse-sub-jsonarray-and-display-image)

please help me already thanks....

```
04-02 07:59:27.767: W/System.err(1737): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: WOW1079.jpg
04-02 07:59:27.815: W/System.err(1737):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
04-02 07:59:27.945: W/System.err(1737):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
04-02 07:59:28.095: W/System.err(1737):     at com.example.benm.DownloadImageTask.getBitmap(DownloadImageTask.java:41)
04-02 07:59:28.315: W/System.err(1737):     at com.example.benm.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:34)
04-02 07:59:28.465: W/System.err(1737):     at com.example.benm.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
04-02 07:59:28.695: W/System.err(1737):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-02 07:59:28.875: W/System.err(1737):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-02 07:59:28.885: W/System.err(1737):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-02 07:59:28.895: W/System.err(1737):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-02 07:59:28.907: W/System.err(1737):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-02 07:59:28.915: W/System.err(1737):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-02 07:59:28.925: W/System.err(1737):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-02 07:59:28.995: W/System.err(1737): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: WOW749.jpg
04-02 07:59:29.036: W/System.err(1737):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
04-02 07:59:29.045: W/System.err(1737):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
04-02 07:59:29.055: W/System.err(1737):     at com.example.benm.DownloadImageTask.getBitmap(DownloadImageTask.java:41)
04-02 07:59:29.066: W/System.err(1737):     at com.example.benm.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:34)
04-02 07:59:29.095: W/System.err(1737):     at com.example.benm.DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(DownloadImageTask.java:1)
04-02 07:59:29.155: W/System.err(1737):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-02 07:59:29.165: W/System.err(1737):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-02 07:59:29.175: W/System.err(1737):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-02 07:59:29.185: W/System.err(1737):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)

here is my code
```

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private String mUrl;
private ImageView mImageView = null;

public DownloadImageTask(String Url, ImageView imageView) {

    mUrl = Url;
    this.mImageView = imageView;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result != null) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(mUrl);
    return bitmap;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl) {
    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mBitmap;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you analyzed your LogCat? The Exception is MalformedURLException, Protocal not found.

Comment: yes ı analized but ı want share fully my LogCat and ı dont know how to solve this problem

Comment: not json problem because ı take other informations for ex: restaurant names only ıcant take image

Comment: in upside ı shared my used code

Comment: The problem is your URL, the exception tells you the URL is malformed (incorrect). Can you post what the URL is?

Comment: Please put the code in your question, by editing your question.

Comment: as i see from your logs, you are passing just the name of the image without complete url -> java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: WOW749.jpg  plz add Log.d("getBitmap", imageUrl);  inside getBitmap function to validate that you are passing the url in right format

Comment: ı couldnt understand where will add ?

Comment: ı am waiting to you friends..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the MalformedURLException depicted in the given logcat, I can say **URL is not valid**. Just check the Image URL value `WOW749.jpg` in response, you aren't getting full but name of the image only.

So I would suggest you to embed webservice URL with Image name while calling `getBitmap()` function, it will solve your issue.

Comment: @EgemenDurmuş check udpated answer, pass full URL to getBitmap() function.

Comment: ı am new started can you give mini example ?

Comment: @EgemenDurmuş yes I can but if your webservice response is in readable format.

Comment: "Restaurants": [
                {
                    "Ix": "1",
                    "ShortDesc": "Ana Restoran",
                    "Header": "STOLİSTA",
                    "PictureUrl_Small": "WOW1079.jpg",
                    "Rating": "5",

Comment: this is my json and ıcan take header shortdesc rating but  cant take only image

Comment: @EgemenDurmuş WOW1079.jpg is the issue, embed full image location either in webservice response or just do string concatenation while calling getBitmap() function. For example: getBitmap("http://mysite.com/images/"+imageUrl)

Comment: public Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl) {
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Comment: you talking about in here is this true ?

Comment: @EgemenDurmuş Can you pleasseeeeee give a try at least?

Comment: in header after log cat ı share my code and ı cant do your advice

Comment: @EgemenDurmuş Sorry I can't help anymore by repeating my answer again and again, because I have already show you exact solution.

Comment: ıwant only where am ı changed on my code can you change ı am new starter

Comment: @EgemenDurmuş doesn't matter, I suggested you in plain English and extremely easy way.