# make listview clickable setOnItemclicklistener method not working

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I made a **listView** with text and image.Now i want to make its items **clickable**.I used **setOnitemclickListener** method but it's not working ..
i think i am doing something wrong
here is my code....

Adapter.java

```
   public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter  {

   private static final String TAG = "Adapter";
    private Activity mActivity;
    public ArrayList<Data> mObjects;

   static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
    TextView name;
    TextView review;
    DownloadImageTask mTask;
   // DownloadImageTask1 mTask1;
   // ImageView photo;
}

public Adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {

    this.mActivity = (Activity) activity;
    this.mObjects = mObjects;
}

public void setObjects(ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {
    this.mObjects = mObjects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Data item = mObjects.get(position);
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
       // viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.name  = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        viewHolder.review  = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());
    holder.name.setText(item.getmConcatinate());
    holder.review.setText(item.getmreview());
    holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ab);
   // holder.photo.setBackgroundResource(0);
    holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);     
    if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
        holder.mTask.execute();
    }
   // holder.mTask1 = new DownloadImageTask1(item.getmImageUrl1(), holder.photo);     
  //  if (!holder.mTask1.isCancelled()) {
  //      holder.mTask1.execute();
  //  }

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return (this.mObjects.size());
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return (this.mObjects.get(position));
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return (position);
}

public AbsListView.RecyclerListener mRecyclerListener = new RecyclerListener( ){

    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        DownloadImageTask imagetask = viewHolder.mTask;
       // DownloadImageTask1 imagetask1 = viewHolder.mTask1;
        if (imagetask != null) {
            imagetask.cancel(true);
        }
       // if (imagetask1 != null) {
      // //     imagetask1.cancel(true);
      //  }
    }

};
```

}

using that content in main class

```
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile3);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    bmImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    loyalitypoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    followers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    following = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    // list13 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setClickable(true);

    // mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new Adapter(this, mSource);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     Log.w("Parsing JSON Data", "Before Item click");


    mListView.setRecyclerListener(mAdapter.mRecyclerListener);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
             Log.w("Parsing JSON Data", "After Item click");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try setting `android:focusable=false` for views in your ListRow.

Comment: @Pragnani still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u will have to make oclicklistener in your adapter only.

```
   viewHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //perform action

            }
        });
```

Comment: will u please make me explain whole scenario

Comment: by using above method i can click on name.Now i want when i click on name it opens a new activity and set the content of name to new activity..I am using the code present in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701747/how-to-parse-sub-jsonarray-and-display-image

Answer (score 0):

Try this ****

ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
        {
              // your action to be performed
        }
    });

}
```