# pass data to new activity from adapter class

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, baseadapter

I made one **custom listview** with image and text.When u **click on image** it ll lead you to new activity.Now i want to **pass image and text** to new activity.i know with **putExtra** method you can pass data but i don't know how can i use it here..
*thanks* in advance...
here is my code for **adapter class**..

Note..I am parsing data from json

Onclick method is used to go on another activity...

```
 public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "Adapter";
private Activity mActivity;
public ArrayList<Data> mObjects;
// /private final Context context;
Context context;

static class ViewHolder {
    static ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
    TextView name;
    TextView review;
    DownloadImageTask mTask;
    String ab[];
    // DownloadImageTask1 mTask1;
    // ImageView photo;
}

public Adapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {

    this.mActivity = (Activity) activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.mObjects = mObjects;

}

public void setObjects(ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {
    this.mObjects = mObjects;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Data item = mObjects.get(position);
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        // viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        viewHolder.review = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());
    holder.name.setText(item.getmConcatinate());

    holder.review.setText(item.getmreview());
    holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ab);
    // holder.photo.setBackgroundResource(0);
    holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);
    if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
        holder.mTask.execute();
    }

    ViewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try122222"); // perform
                                                                    // action
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LargeView.class);

            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    // holder.mTask1 = new DownloadImageTask1(item.getmImageUrl1(),
    // holder.photo);
    // if (!holder.mTask1.isCancelled()) {
    // holder.mTask1.execute();
    // }

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return (this.mObjects.size());
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return (this.mObjects.get(position));
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return (position);
}

public AbsListView.RecyclerListener mRecyclerListener = new RecyclerListener() {

    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        DownloadImageTask imagetask = viewHolder.mTask;
        // DownloadImageTask1 imagetask1 = viewHolder.mTask1;
        if (imagetask != null) {
            imagetask.cancel(true);
        }
        // if (imagetask1 != null) {
        // // imagetask1.cancel(true);
        // }
    }

};
```

code in main activity.class

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile3);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    bmImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    loyalitypoints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    followers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    following = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    // list13 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setClickable(true);






    // mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new Adapter(this,c,mSource );
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    Log.w("Parsing JSON Data", "Before Item click");

    mListView.setRecyclerListener(mAdapter.mRecyclerListener);

 }


        public String getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this way:

```
ViewHolder.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Parsing JSON Data", "Before user try122222"); // perform
                                                                    // action
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LargeView.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", "dhaval");
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

pass image in intent is BAD idea. just pass URL, Image Path, image name whatever you have..

like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LargeView.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "dhaval");
intent.putExtra("imangeUTL", "www.xyz.com/images/test.png");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: look at the code of selected answer of this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701747/how-to-parse-sub-jsonarray-and-display-image  and tell me how can i get this data in onclick method

Comment: add this line in setOnClickListener  : String title = item.getmTitle()

Comment: yes its working ..but on click i am not getting the right data ..thanks a lot